Is there a way to suppress warnings but only for a given directory in Sphinx?
I am generating API documentation using autoapi.extension in Sphinx. It is a large repo, and not all of the doc strings are well formatted and this generates a lot of sphinx docutils warnings. However I also want sphinx to fail on warnings for the rst files that are manually written. The autogenerated api gets written to a specific directory, so I was wondering if there was a way to ignore warnings just in that specific section
Currently I am suppressing all docutil warnings with the suppressed_warnings in the conf.py. Fixing all of the doc strings in the repo is not really an option, as this is a large repo with a lot of people contributing.

You can raise a feature request via https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues but I doubt this might help most sphinx users. People can always filter out useful lines from console output with another tool.

Would the filtered warnings still affect the fail on warnings functionality?
